# Help identify SMD (Schottky?) diode (marked "NU")

Tags: diodes, identification, surface-mount

I'm trying to see if I can get [this thing](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/610034/feedback-requested-on-diy-dummy-battery) fixed. I already have a spare from AliExpress but it would be cool to see if I can get my DIY one fixed.

It's this diode marked only "NU" and is ab-so-lutely tiny:

[image: Diode]

I only have through-hole diodes available currently. I was considering soldering a similar specced one to a bit of 0.1mm enameled wire and from there to the PCB. I have room to spare in the enclosure. I could also just bridge the pads and see if that works but I'd rather not. Ordering an SMD replacement is an option, just not a likely one.

I tried the [SMD code book](http://www.marsport.org.uk/smd/mainframe.htm) but couldn't find anything for "NU".

Comment: It is likely that the layout has an effect on the performance, so using wires and especially a different diode will cause problems. The best chances to fix the board is pribably to reverse-engineer that part of the circuit and find a suitable SMD replacement. The product marking "NU" does often not help much as that's difficult to find with search engines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks to be a [DZ2J100](https://docs.rs-online.com/dbe2/0900766b80e23bd2.pdf). Marking confirmed in datasheet.

Comment: Thank you! Now to find out where to get one (or a handful) or what a decent equivalent is.